# Adding dynamic tikzpicture with newcommand inside new command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, errors

I have a side block command that lets me add content on the side of the page very easily but now I want to have the choice to add some kind of chart or dynamic graphic content in it too.

Lets say I want to add a skill/theme and a level of difficulty, instead of having it written I will add an icon for the skill and I want to add a nice stylized bar to show the level of difficulty.

This is my basic side block command:

```
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\newenvironment{aside}{%
    \let\oldsection\section
    \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
    }
    \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
        \begin{flushright}
            \obeycr
        }{%
            \restorecr
        \end{flushright}
    \end{textblock}
    \let\section\oldsection
}
```

Then I tried to modify it to be able to add a new rectangle with tikz for each "\barline" (the rectangle is a test).

```
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos,tikz}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\newenvironment{aside}{%
    \let\oldsection\section
    \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
    }
    \newcommand{\barline}[2]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[fill=chartorange, rounded corners=0.08cm](-1,0) rectangle (1.5,0.5) {##1};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
        \begin{flushright}
            \obeycr
        }{%
            \restorecr
        \end{flushright}
    \end{textblock}
    \let\section\oldsection
}
```

Using it like:

```
\begin{aside}
\section{Languages}
\barline{French}{70};
\end{aside}
```

My problem is that I must do something wrong since I get a lot of errors :

```
Option clash for package tikz. \setlength 
Command \barline already defined. \begin{aside}
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path.Did you forget a semicolon?. \barline{French}{70}
```

Option clash is a package issue that I must look into.
I thought that my new command would override the command if it exists.
Why is there an issue with the semicolon since I put it in the newcommand?

I hope you will be able to help me, I'm quite new with things more complicated than a simple report with LaTeX and it takes time to learn.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` if you want to redefine an existing command.

Comment: Do not define `\barline` within `aside`, but globally.

Comment: Otherwise, the second time you use the environment, `\barline` is already defined and not new, so `\newcommand` fails.

Comment: Are you sure you want to redefine `\section` like that?